# converting binary to decimal c program

Tags: c, binary

I need help writing a binary conversion program in c. I need a way to increase the size of an array depending on how many bits are in a binary number, put the 1's and 0's in another array and add the numbers in the first array to get the converted number in decimal. I'm learning c programming as my first programming language.
here's what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf("Please input binary number to convert to decimal.");
    Scanf("%d");
    for(i=2;i<= /*number of integers in binary number*/;i++ )
    {
        int i
        char conversiontable [2][i] ={
            /*array1*/{'1','2',},
            /*array2*/{}
        };
        /*inputs 110001101*/
        /*increase size of array1 according to number of 1's and 0's in the binary number*/
        /*fill empty slots in array 1 with the output of (2^2)2 starting in slot 3 and add 1 to the number outside the parenthesis for each slot*/
        /*put binary number in array 2*/
        /*add together the numbers in array 1 in correspondence to wherever there is a 1 in array 2*/

        /*example*/
        /*1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256*/
        /*1,1,0,0, 0, 1, 1,  0,  1*/

        /*1+2+32+64+256=355*/
        /*outputs 355 for answer*/
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your approach is not the best, maybe if you store the binary number in a char array and then analyze it everything goes easier ;).

If I were you I do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    char binary [20];
    printf ("Input the binary number:  ");
    scanf ("%s", binary);

    int length = 0;
    while (binary [length] != '\0')
       ++length;

    int decimal = 0;
    for (int i = length - 1; i > -1; --i)
    {
        if (binary [i] == '1')
            decimal += pow (2, length - i - 1);
    }

    printf ("To decimal: %d\n", decimal);

    return 0;
}
```